# A question concerning $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x^{8}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

We are given the equation
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x^{8}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi^{A}}{\sqrt{B}}\left[\sqrt{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{C}\right)}}\cos{\left(\frac{D\pi}{E}\right)}-\sqrt{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{C}\right)}}\sin{\left(\frac{F\pi}{E}\right)}\right],$$ where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ and $F$ are positive integers such that $\frac{F\pi}{E}<\frac{\pi}{C}<\frac{D\pi}{E}$ are acute angles, and $D$, $E$ and $F$ are pairwise coprime. The objective is to find the value of $A+B+C+D+E+F$.

Substituting $x=\sin t$ gives $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} (cost)^2\frac 1{(\sin t)^8 +1} \,\mathrm{d}t$.

I don't know what to do next. I tried integration by parts but got nowhere.

Comment: Nice nickname! :)

Comment: Peter. oh thks!!

Comment: Did you mean $(\sin x)^8$ rather than $\sin(x^8)$? $\qquad$

Comment: oh..my mistake (sinx)^8 is correct

Comment: It is customary to use $\text{“}\sin^8 x\text{''}$ to mean $(\sin x)^8$.  It's not great notation, but it's standard.  One objection (I think expressed by no less than Gauss himself) is that $\sin^3 x$ _ought_ to mean $\sin(\sin(\sin x)))$.  But it's standard that it means $(\sin x)^3$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy For the iteration, a fallback is then to use $\sin^{(3)} x$ (I've seen that quite often). Now, the problem becomes that $\sin^{(3)} $ can also be used for the third derivative of $\sin$...

Comment: @MichaelHardy I never really understood why people don't just say $(\sin x)^n$. Are the brackets really that inconvenient?

Comment: If $x=\sin t$ then $dx = \cos t\,dt$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \cos t$, so $$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^8+1} \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2 t}{\sin^8 t+1}\, dt. $$  If all else fails, the tangent half-angle substitution will work here, but sometimes something simpler will do it. Another possibility is a rationalizing substitution at the outset rather than a trigonometric substitution. (But I don't think the latter will work in this case.) $\qquad$

Comment: I still suspect something less involved than the tangent half-angle substitution will do it, although a rationalizing substitution at the outset will not, unless I missed something. $\qquad$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 : I agree that that's a better notation, but the exponent on the function itself has become standard with trigonometric functions. $\qquad$

Comment: The LHS of your equation is a certain real number that can be calculated using residue calculus, or suitable substitutions. Nobody short of Ramanujan would come up with the "Ansatz" on the right hand side without having seen the solution beforehand. This problem is **utterly phony**.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^8+1}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^8\theta+1}d\theta=\frac14\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\cos^8\theta+1}d\theta$$
Then
$$\frac{1-u^2}{u^8+1}=\frac{1-u^2}{\prod_{k=0}^7(u-\omega_k)}=\sum_{k=0}^7\frac{A_k}{u-\omega_k}$$
Where $\omega_k=e^{i\phi_k}=\cos\phi_k+i\sin\phi_k$ and $\phi_k=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}8$. Then
$$\begin{align}\lim_{u\rightarrow\omega_k}\frac{(u-\omega_k)(1-u^2)}{u^8+1}&=\frac{1-\omega_k^2}{8\omega_k^7}=\frac{\omega_k^3-\omega_k}{8}=\frac{\omega_k^2\cdot2i\sin\phi_k}{8}\\
&=\lim_{u\rightarrow\omega_k}\sum_{j=0}^7A_j\frac{u-\omega_k}{u-\omega_j}=\sum_{j=0}^7A_j\delta_{jk}=A_k\end{align}$$
And
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta-\omega_k}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2-\omega_k}=\frac2i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{i\theta}d\theta}{e^{2i\theta}-2\omega_ke^{i\theta}+1}=\frac2i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^2-2\omega_kz+1}$$
The root inside the unit circle is $z_1=\omega_k-\omega_k^{1/2}\sqrt{2i\sin\theta_k}$ and its residue is
$$\frac1{z_1-z_2}=\frac1{-2\omega_k^{1/2}\sqrt{2i\sin\theta_k}}$$
Putting all of the above together,
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^8+1}dx=\frac14\sum_{k=0}^7\frac2i2\pi i\frac{\omega_k^2\cdot2i\sin\theta_k}{8(-2)\omega_k^{1/2}\sqrt{2i\sin\theta_k}}=-\frac{\pi}{16}(1+i)\sum_{k=0}^7\omega_k^{3/2}\sqrt{\sin\theta_k}$$
We can see that $\sin\theta_0=\sin\theta_3=-\sin\theta_4=-\sin\theta_7=\sin\frac{\pi}8$. Also $\sin\theta_1=\sin\theta_2=-\sin\theta_5=-\sin\theta_6=\cos\frac{\pi}8$. Thus
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^8+1}dx&=-\frac{\pi}{16}(1+i)\left[\sqrt{\sin\theta_0}\left(e^{\frac{3\pi i}{16}}+e^{\frac{21\pi i}{16}}+ie^{\frac{27\pi i}{16}}+ie^{\frac{45\pi i}{16}}\right)\right.\\
&\left.+\sqrt{\sin\theta_1}\left(e^{\frac{9\pi i}{16}}+e^{\frac{15\pi i}{16}}+ie^{\frac{33\pi i}{16}}+ie^{\frac{39\pi i}{16}}\right)\right]\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{16}(1+i)\left[\sqrt{\sin\theta_0}\left(\sin\frac{5\pi}{16}+i\sin\frac{3\pi}{16}-\sin\frac{3\pi}{16}-i\sin\frac{5\pi}{16}\right.\right.\\
&\left.\left.+i\sin\frac{3\pi}{16}+\sin\frac{5\pi}{16}-i\sin\frac{5\pi}{16}-\sin\frac{3\pi}{16}\right)\right.\\
&\left.+\sqrt{\sin\theta_1}\left(-\cos\frac{7\pi}{16}+i\cos\frac{\pi}{16}-\cos\frac{\pi}{16}+i\cos\frac{7\pi}{16}\right.\right.\\
&\left.\left.+i\cos\frac{\pi}{16}-\cos\frac{7\pi}{16}+i\cos\frac{7\pi}{16}-\cos\frac{\pi}{16}\right)\right]\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{16}(1+i)\left[\sqrt{\sin\theta_0}\left(2(-1+i)\sin\frac{3\pi}{16}+2(1-i)\sin\frac{5\pi}{16}\right)\right.\\
&\left.\sqrt{\sin\theta_1}\left(2(-1+i)\cos\frac{\pi}{16}+2(-1+i)\cos\frac{7\pi}{16}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}4\left[\sqrt{\sin\frac{\pi}8}\left(\sin\frac{3\pi}{16}-\sin\frac{5\pi}{16}\right)+\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}8}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{16}+\cos\frac{7\pi}{16}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}4\left[\sqrt{\sin\frac{\pi}8}\left(-2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin\frac{\pi}{16}\right)+\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}8}\left(2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos\frac{3\pi}{16}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\left[\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}8}\cos\frac{3\pi}{16}-\sqrt{\sin\frac{\pi}8}\sin\frac{\pi}{16}\right]\end{align}$$
So that means $A=1$, $B=8$, $C=8$, $D=3$, $E=16$, $F=1$, and
$$A+B+C+D+E+F=1+8+8+3+16+1=37$$